# How to remap repeating commands i.e. <number><command>?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

By default, vim lets you type 5G (5 then shift + g) to go to line 5. Instead, I don't want to have to press the shift key. Pressing `<S-g>` does something different than just `5<S-g>`. How can I remap a command that takes a number for repeated executions?

Something like: `nnoremap <number>g <number>G`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
nnoremap g G
```

But this will not work well, as there are a lot of key mapping beginning with `g`. So Vim has to wait a timeout (default 1000 msec) to be sure that no other key is pressed after the `g`. The `g` could be the start of 'gg' or 'g$' or ...

So after you pressed `5g` nothing will happen for one second. Than the cursor jumps to line 5.

If you want to know about the other key mappings starting with 'g' just enter ':help g' and then hit `<tab>`. Lots of stuff.

Comment: Thanks for this. I realized soon after remapping g was a bad idea haha! Ill check out the help text for that command.

Answer (score 3):

Even though OP accepted the existing answer this feels incomplete to me.

First, the answer has a well-considered warning about remapping `g` but there
is no mention of `<count>gg` as a *near-synonym* for `<count>G`. (They differ only when the count is omitted. By default `gg` goes to the first line and `G` to the last.). Perhaps entering <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> is less annoying to OP than <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and we have a nice, easy workaround...

The other thing that feels unaddressed is the subject of the question which is notably more generic than what has actually been discussed. It happens to be a good question, about applying a repeat count to a mapped command, but folks who come here from google will have to keep looking if it's not answered. So...

From Normal mode, if one precedes a command with a count and that command enters a vimscript/ex context we can retrieve the count from that context with the built-in variable `v:count`.

I'll use it in an example applicable to the more specific question we've been addressing...

```
nnoremap XX :<C-U>exe 'norm! ' . v:count . 'G'<CR>
```

In place of `XX` choose any key or keys you like better than <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and this will
give you a replacement for `<count>G`.

*FYI about the use of `<C-U>` (see `:h c_CTRL-U`): this is required to clear the command line before the mapped command is applied. Normally when we enter a number followed by `:` the command line is pre-populated with a line range. In this case we don't want that.*

Comment: Nice to know `<count>gg`.  You might need to explain `<c-u>`, some user might consider it as a mistake, they don't know :h N: .  You command also need a trailing `<cr>`.

Comment: @dedowsdi Thanks for the heads up about the `<cr>` that I left off. And you're right about explaining `<c-u>`...I was being lazy and planned to fill it out later. :)